# Как запретить масштабирование страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Видел много сайтов где не получается увеличить двумя пальцами. Как это осуществить?

Comment: В head положите `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Holter..............не за что :)